# Magento - Add button [+ Add Field] that adds/shows a new text field in system.xml

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have a custom module with optional text fields (shown via the *standard text field option* in **system.xml**). What I'd like to do is to show 1 mandatory text field and have a button that says something like **[+ Add Field]**. When that button is pressed, another text field is added. I'd like to do this for **up to** 10 total text fields (max). Can someone help me to accomplish this or point me to a nice tutorial on how to do this?

**EDIT 7/10/12 @ 11:30AM**

I've been working on this and so far I can get the text fields to show up. However I have a few issues...

1. When pressing the "Save Config" button, none of the values entered in these dynamically created textfields actually save.
2. Is there a way to limit how many text fields actually save?
3. I'm unsure of the correct way to retrieve the text field(s) data. This is mostly due to the fact that I cannot save the values...(I will add another update after #1 is fixed if I need help with this...)

My **System.xml** file has this in it (directly related to this)..

```
<labels translate="label">
    <label>This is some label</label>
    <comment>This is some comment.</comment>
    <tooltip><![CDATA[This is some tooltip]]></tooltip>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <frontend_model>Company_Namespace/adminhtml_textfields</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized</backend_model>
    <sort_order>50</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</labels>
```

My custom **Textfields.php** (frontend_model) file contents:

```
<?php

class Company_Namespace_Block_Adminhtml_Textfields extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
protected $_addRowButtonHtml = array();
protected $_removeRowButtonHtml = array();

protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $this->setElement($element);

    $html = '<div id="code_label_textfields_template" style="display:none">';
    $html .= $this->_getRowTemplateHtml();
    $html .= '</div>';

    $html .= '<ul id="code_label_textfields_container">';

    if ($this->_getValue('method')) {
        foreach ($this->_getValue('method') as $i=>$f) {
            if ($i) {
                $html .= $this->_getRowTemplateHtml($i);
            }
        }
    }

    $html .= '</ul>';


    $html .= $this->_getAddRowButtonHtml('code_label_textfields_container', 'code_label_textfields_template', $this->__('Button Label Here'));

    return $html;
}

protected function _getRowTemplateHtml()
{
    $html = '<li>';

    $html .= '<div style="margin:5px 0 10px;">';
    $html .= '<input class="input-text" name="'.$this->getElement()->getName().'" value="'.$this->_getValue('price/'.$i).'" '.$this->_getDisabled().'/> ';

    $html .= $this->_getRemoveRowButtonHtml();
    $html .= '</div>';

    $html .= '</li>';

    return $html;
}



protected function _getDisabled()
{
    return $this->getElement()->getDisabled() ? ' disabled' : '';
}

protected function _getValue($key)
{
    return $this->getElement()->getData('value/'.$key);
}

protected function _getSelected($key, $value)
{
    return $this->getElement()->getData('value/'.$key)==$value ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
}

protected function _getAddRowButtonHtml($container, $template, $title='Add')
{
    if (!isset($this->_addRowButtonHtml[$container])) {
        $this->_addRowButtonHtml[$container] = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                ->setType('button')
                ->setClass('add '.$this->_getDisabled())
                ->setLabel($this->__($title))
                //$this->__('Add')
                ->setOnClick("Element.insert($('".$container."'), {bottom: $('".$template."').innerHTML})")
                ->setDisabled($this->_getDisabled())
                ->toHtml();
    }
    return $this->_addRowButtonHtml[$container];
}

protected function _getRemoveRowButtonHtml($selector='li', $title='Remove')
{
    if (!$this->_removeRowButtonHtml) {
        $this->_removeRowButtonHtml = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                ->setType('button')
                ->setClass('delete v-middle '.$this->_getDisabled())
                ->setLabel($this->__($title))
                //$this->__('Remove')
                ->setOnClick("Element.remove($(this).up('".$selector."'))")
                ->setDisabled($this->_getDisabled())
                ->toHtml();
    }
    return $this->_removeRowButtonHtml;
}
}
```

***What am I missing, especially for saving values???***

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [`system.xml`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/etc/system.xml#L189) and the [`Mage_GoogleCheckout_Block_Adminhtml_Shipping_Merchant`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/Block/Adminhtml/Shipping/Merchant.php) block for an example. It's a little convoluted, but it works. You can see this in the Merchant Calculated settings in Google Checkout.

Comment: This is working but is there no way to limit how many fields populate? I'm working on this section but it does not seem to take any limiting...$html .= $this->_getAddRowButtonHtml('some_container', 'some_template', $this->__('Some Label'));. Oh and how would you retrieve the data from the textfield(s)?

Comment: They are stored in core_config_data in a serialized array.

Comment: Thanks again for your continued support. I've added a lot more detail. In GoogleCheckout module, in the Merchant.php, it had a getShippingMethods() function that seemed to do the saving?? Can you help elaborate because I've been having trouble saving values (they don't save). I've entered a lot more detail above. Thanks!